# Read all git cached password

Tags: passwords, password-management, credentials, git

in a 10+ people team we access the same ubuntu VM and we 'su' to the same user. On that user we make use of [git-credential-cache](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache) feature to not type our personal password again and again.

**As all password are stored using the socket owned by the same user, can a simple program retrieve all plaint text passwords? If yes, any pointers on how to demonstrate it?**

If yes, we should definately change the way we cache passwords (a session token would be fine for us).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `git-credential-cache` has the [built-in functionality](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35f6318d44379452d8d33e880d8df0267b4a0cd0/credential-cache.c#L115) to read the cache contents, you just need to run this command to obtain the stored credentials, including password in plain-text:

```
$ echo -ne 'username=<repo_user>\nprotocol=<repo_protocol>\nhost=<repo_host>\n' | git credential-cache get
```

For instance, if you are using https://git@github.com as your repository, you could extract stored credentials by doing this:

```
$ echo -ne 'username=git\nprotocol=https\nhost=github.com\n' | git credential-cache get
  username=your_github_user
  password=your_github_password_in_plaintext
```

The "username" part in the query is only required if you have more than one user working on the same repository (which I guess is your situation).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Now I will have to look for alternative (more secure) solutions to avoid typing passwords every time.

Comment: I found unexpected behavior when a custom socket path is set.  For example, if you ran `git config --global credential.helper cache --socket=/custom/path/to/file` you have to set the same custom socket with credential-cache commands, as it won't be read from the global config.  For example, `echo url=https://github.com | git credential-cache --socket=/custom/path/to/file get` and `git credential-cache --socket=/custom/path/to/file exit` were required to read and erase what was stored after a `git pull`.